# All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples when using Keras with the TensorFlow backend (ask again)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

**Sorry, don't know how to ask a good question for the first time, so ask again.**
I've created a model with multiple inputs and outputs. The structure of the model is shown below.
*Don't have enough reputation to post image, so the image is [in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvQhp.png).*

```py
inputV = keras.layers.Input(shape=(4096,),name='inputV') #input for visible task
inputH = keras.layers.Input(shape=(4096,),name='inputH') #input for hidden task
hiddenTaskLayer = keras.layers.Dense(14,use_bias=False,activation='sigmoid',name='hiddenTask')
outputV = hiddenTaskLayer(inputV)
outputH = hiddenTaskLayer(inputH)
visibleTaskLayer = keras.layers.Dense(7,use_bias=False,activation='softmax',name='visibleTask')
outputV = visibleTaskLayer(outputV)
outputV = keras.layers.Activation('linear',name='outputV')(outputV)
outputH = keras.layers.Activation('linear',name='outputH')(outputH)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[inputH,inputV],outputs=[outputH,outputV])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss={'outputH': 'msle', 'outputV': 'categorical_crossentropy'},
              loss_weights={'outputH': .5, 'outputV': 0.5})
```

```
Model: "model_2"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
inputH (InputLayer)             [(None, 4096)]       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
inputV (InputLayer)             [(None, 4096)]       0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
hiddenTask (Dense)              (None, 14)           57344       inputV[0][0]                     
                                                                 inputH[0][0]                     
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
visibleTask (Dense)             (None, 7)            98          hiddenTask[0][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
outputH (Activation)            (None, 14)           0           hiddenTask[1][0]                 
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
outputV (Activation)            (None, 7)            0           visibleTask[0][0]                
==================================================================================================
Total params: 57,442
Trainable params: 57,442
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

However when i tried to fit the model

```py
model.fit({'inputH': XforHT, 'inputV': XforVT},
          {'outputH': YforHT, 'outputV': YforVT},
          epochs=10000, batch_size=100,
          shuffle=True,validation_split=0.33, 
          callbacks=[tensorboard_callback, cp_callback, scheduler_callback])
```

with the data set i provided

```py
print(XforHT.shape)
print(YforHT.shape)
print(XforVT.shape)
print(YforVT.shape)
```

```
(593, 4096)
(593, 14)
(327, 4096)
(327, 7)
```

error raises as:

```
ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(593, 4096), (327, 4096)]
```

I know that if cut the number of samples in XforHT to 327, the codes will run well, but i don't want to do that.
I do have different number of samples for different inputs and outputs, and i am sure that each output has the same number of samples of their corresponding input. what can i do **without abandoning some of my samples or looking for some new samples**?

Comment: No, it is not possible, multi-task learning requires the same number of samples, as forward and backward passes are done all at the same time with one sample for each input/output.

Comment: Your first question is clear, well organized and explains your issue in details. Keep going !